# How can you tell who owns a page in Google+?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-pages

There are many fake pages in Google+ and I want to know who owns each page.

Where do I look to find out the owner of a Google Plus page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an option to include an e-mail in the profile of the page. If the e-mail address has been verified there will be a checkmark next to it.

How much you can trust an e-mail address and how much information you can glean from it all depends.

Further, one can add a G+ button to their website which points back to the Google+ page. I'd say that's a pretty good indication, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know.

But I very sincerly hope that the answer is "You can't", in the same way that you cannot find out who the admins of a Facebook page are unless you are made into one of those admins.

If people can find out, then I will definitely have to re-think whether I use Google+ pages at all.

Why - well I'm building some websites that I wasn to grow into entitles independent of me one day, either by me selling them, or handing them on to another volunteer.  I don't want my face linked to them now, or in future.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can not directly tell who is the owner of the page.

Page administration is divided between owner (1) and managers (up to 50).

The only way to figure out page ownership is if they either made a mistake and left the email address in the contact information (and as Al above said - do you believe the email / profile owner is real?), or by doing an analysis of which pages and or sites benefit the most from links out from the page. Figure out which page sites have the most prominent links out and chances are you will find the website which "owns" the page.

Then you need to figure out who owns the website. Many site owners are sloppy and have their information left directly open for all to see with a simple "whois" search - which will give you the registration info.